# MSal.js --> ClientAuthError: no_tokens_found: No tokens were found for the given scopes

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have a single page application (SPA), this application logs in to the azure ad using the preview version of msal.js --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser

I am using the authorization code flow with pkce.

Logging in works fine and also accessing the Microsoft Graph rest API works. No problem there.

The trouble starts when I would like to access my own Spring rest API. I followed this manual:

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

So I created two app registrations, one that is exposing an api by creating a scope and for the other one I added the permission for that scope. Just like the manual is telling me...

In me single page app I have the following code:

```
getData: function(){
    const self = this;
    //once login is successful and redirects with tokens, call Graph API (or other api?)

    if (self.myMSALObj.getAccount()) {

      var request = {
          scopes: ["api://fee6e03c-9eb2-41f4-805b-78ac5f4bc5f6/Files.Read"]         
      };


      const tokenResponse = self.myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request)
      .then(response =>{
            console.log(response)
           self.$request({
                url: "http://localhost:8888/api/todolist",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.accessToken },
                //headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.idToken },
                timeout: 300 * 1000,
                error: function(xhr, status) {
                    console.error(xhr);
                },
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                  console.log(data)
                },
                complete: function() {}
            });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
          if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
              // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
              return self.myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(request)
          }
      });


   }        
  }
```

So when i call this function It is trying to fetch new accesstokens for this specific scope and after that it should call my rest service but it is throwing the following error:

> ClientAuthError: no_tokens_found: No tokens were found for the given
>   scopes, and no authorization code was passed to acquireToken. You must
>   retrieve an authorization code before making a call to acquireToken().
>   Scopes: api://fee6e03c-9eb2-41f4-805b-78ac5f4bc5f6/files.read
>   offline_access

If I use the microsoft graph api with the User.read scope... I have no problem at all...  Does anybody know what I am missing here?

Thanks for your help in advance,

Regards,

Peter

Comment: Can you please clarify the version of MSAL you are using? That error appears to come from the betas of @azure/msal-browser, not @azure/msal.

Comment: You are right I am using@azure/msal-browser instead of @azure/msal I`ll change this my post. Thanks.

Comment: See this thread: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1718

Comment: So it is a bug....